# Onclick Event for Notification not working in Android

Tags: android, android-notifications

i'm sending one notification from background service. If i click on that notification its not calling to perticular activity for some times. (Few times only its calling ).

this is my code:

```
    private void postNotification(String msg, int beaconID) {
    if(!notifyMsg.equalsIgnoreCase(msg)){
        notifyMsg = msg;

        Log.e(TAG, "---------postNotification------- called");


            notifyIntent = new Intent(this,
                    WelcomeHotel.class);


        notifyIntent.putExtra("content", msg);
        notifyIntent.putExtra("from_activity", ""+TAG);

        notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                BeaconMyService.this, 0, /*new Intent[] { notifyIntent }*/ notifyIntent,
                /*PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT*/0);

        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(
                BeaconMyService.this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Monitoring Region").setContentText(msg)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "Monitoring Region", ""+msg, pendingIntent);

        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

```
setLastEventInfo()
```

This method was deprecated in API level 11. Use Notification.Builder instead.

---

```
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
```

should to

```
new Notification.Builder(BeaconMyService.this)
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
    ...
```

---

If you use minApi - pre-Honeycomb, you should to change one string

```
//new Notification.Builder(BeaconMyService.this)
new NotificationCompat.Builder(BeaconMyService.this)
```